# jenkins/github : how to merge current branch into another using blue ocean

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-blueocean

using jenkins with blue ocean,
I've configured a pipeline mapped to a private github repo.

if the tests are OK, I want to merge the current branch (let's say master) into another (let's say production) and then call a tooling of my own to deploy the content of the production branch.

Blue ocean's setup process has configured my acces to github for me (using oauth https token).
in addition I've set up an ssh key for the jenkins user and registered it into github.

when I call git fetch, it fail because it try to fetch using https, and so do not use my ssh key.
How can i use built in jekins auth mechanism in order to call `git fetch`

here are the incriminated part

    `stage('confirm deployment') {
      steps {
        input(message: 'deploy to production?', ok: 'Yes, deploy')
      }
    }
    stage('merge into production branch') {
      steps {
        sh '''git fetch
git checkout production
git merge $BRANCH_NAME
git checkout $BRANCH_NAME'''
      }
    }`

here is the relevant output : 

`+ git fetch
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
script returned exit code 128`

Comment: I ended up with a shell script that clone the repo from gitHub in another directory and manage all the operations there. It's far from performant, but it's the only working solution that I found